# Относительный clip-path css

Tags: css

Недавно я использовал `clip-path`, чтобы сделать декоративную обрезку изображения. Я создал маску в Inkscape и *"вырвал"* из итогового svg `path`, всё сработало за исключением того, что маска не растягивается по размеру изображения, а остаётся по размеру холста, поскольку координаты в path указаны абсолютные.

Вот пример:

```css
section {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#clipme {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FF8864;
  clip-path: path('m8.3634 9.8309c68.284-6.1882 39.013 12.331 80.804-1.0687 6.0561-1.9419 18.525 0.77696 32.616 1.0687-19.889 102.68 18.582 69.02 0 110.1-42.039-3.5946-82.783-33.22-113.42 0-27.365-85.399 32.654-92.947 0-110.1z');
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id='clipme'/>
</section>
```

Возможно ли это исправить на уровне css?
Может есть инструменты, которые могут преобразовывать абсолютные величины в относительные? Ну и раз уж я упомянул **inkscape**, может в нём я могу настроить это?